logit model - labor probability(odds ratio)
The logit model is given:
$$
\text{Labor probability} = \alpha + \beta_1 \cdot \text{income} + \beta_2 \cdot \text{age} + \beta_3 \cdot \text{education} + \beta_4 \cdot \text{young kids} + \beta_5 \cdot \text{old kids} + \beta_6 \cdot \text{foreign} + \beta_7 \cdot \text{age}^2
$$
I want to know how to calculate the change in odds ratio when other variables are fixed as mean values in the logit model and education variable is increased from 9 to 12.

Don't you mean change in odd rather than odds ratio?  And you could just calculate it.

That is not a logit model. If you said the logit of the probability is equal to that expression, that would be a logit model. If the probability itself, rather than the logit of the probability, is equal to that expression, that is not a logit model. And notice how quickly the model you've proposed, which doesn't mention logits, gives you supposed probabilities that are more than $1$ or less than $0.$
